# Trying to add user to group that exists in /etc/group not working

Tags: debian, users, group, useradd

I'm trying to add a list of users to different groups on a debian VM. I am using the following sequence of commands in my bash script:

```
getent group $uid || groupadd $uid                        #add group before adding user
useradd -s $shell -m -d $users_directory -g $uid $uname   #add user with group id $uid
```

However running this  prints out the following:

```
groupadd: group '5067' already exists
useradd: group '5067' does not exist
```

looking at my groups with `cut-d: -f1 /etc/group` I see that '5067' exists there, but when I run `groups` all I see is 'root' as the lone group.

Any tips?

Comment: No linux handy, but a group has a name and a gid, and having an all-digit name is likely to confuse programs that want to take a "name-or-gid" as parameter. (I'm not convinced `groupadd $uid` will create a group with gid `$uid` and not a group with name `$uid`.)

Answer (score 6):

Calling `groupadd` with a numeric group id is going to create a group *named* `5067`.  E.g.:

```
# groupadd 5067
# grep 5067 /etc/group
5067:x:1000:
```

When you pass a numeric identifier to `useradd -g ...`, it looks only at group *ids*.  So even though a group *named* `5067` exists:

```
# useradd -g 5067 testuser
useradd: group '5067' does not exist
```

I suspect this is the root of your problem.

That you don't see the new group when running `groups` is normal. Any new groups you've added a user to won't take effect until that user logs in. If the user is already logged in, they need to log out and log back in (os start a new login shell). That's why you don't see the new group in the output of `groups` although you do see it in `/etc/group`.

Comment: I added the bit about `groups` not working to your answer instead of writing my own since you'd already done a better job of explaining the issue with the numerical ids.

Answer (score 1):

re: the groups command showing only root.

If you simply type groups, you get the response for *your* uid.
You need to use groups $uname to see the groups for that user.

Also, be aware that useradd may create a new group for the user with the same name. You can use -N to prevent that. Look in /etc/login.defs and /etc/default/useradd to check on option defaults.